# Wrapping exceptions in more meaningful exceptions for the end user's benefit

Tags: exception

In exception handling, it is sometimes a good practise to wrap an exception in a more meaningful exception for the user's benefit. E.g. wrap a timeoutexception in a networkexception.

However, every exception that is thrown would be alien to the user. Woud it then not be best to wrap every exception which the user may see? And if this is the case, some custom exceptions just for this purpose may need to be created, which seems like a very inefficient thing to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also thought about this issue before.

I don't think you should wrap every exception the user may see because while it doesn't matter to the user what specific exception was thrown, it does matter to you.  If you went by what the user should see you'd probably end up wrapping everything at the highest level and you'd lose all specificity in your code.

Let's say you wrote a method to contact a web service and parse the response.  In your code you might want to discern between a server error (NetworkException) and a parsing error (IOException).  For both you'd just tell the user "an error occurred" since they don't care what specific thing went wrong.  However, you might want to log a different message or respond some other way in response to either one.